# UL style attribute is changed to display:block from display:none but this happens in fraction of second unable to take list of li elements from ul

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-iedriver

**Dropdown** - On clicking on div,Ul style attribute is changed to display:block from display:none but this happens in fraction of second unable to take list of li elements from ul

```
<div id="main_filter" class="drop-select-wrap">
    <span data-title="Active Clinic Patients" data-value="101" class="optionValue ov-gradient">Active Clinic Patients&nbsp;&nbsp;▼</span>

    <ul class="dropSelect" id="parentFilter" style="display: none; width: 175px;">

        <li id="filterTypes" data-value="102" onclick="tier1FilterChanged(this);" data-rel="My Active Patients">
            <span data-title="My Active Patients">My Active Patients</span>
        </li>

        <li id="filterTypes" data-value="101" onclick="tier1FilterChanged(this);" data-rel="Active Clinic Patients">
            <span data-title="Active Clinic Patients">Active Clinic Patients</span>
        </li>

        <li id="filterTypes" data-value="126" onclick="tier1FilterChanged(this);" data-rel="Inactive Patients">
            <span data-title="Inactive Patients">Inactive Patients</span>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

**Initial :**
On page load, i am having dropdown of above code where - UL tag is having attribute style="display: none; , so all li elements are hidden . Only span value i.e. default selected value is displayed.
In this case, for dropdown on page load - Active Clinic Patients is displayed.

**On Click of dropdown :**

Once i click on dropdown, UL attribute is changed to style="display: block;"
and li elements are visible.

**Problem Faced :**

On clicking on span , dropdown values are displayed for fraction of second - so unable to handle Ul style attribute changes and selecting value from li.

I am struggling for this, it would be great if anyone can provide some solution.
Thanks in advance.

**Tried Code Snippet :**

```
private IWebElement parentFilter => driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='main_filter'][1]/span"));

public void SelectFilter(string filterOption)
        {
            IWebElement elementToShow = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//ul[@class='dropSelect']"));
            ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].style='display: block;'", elementToShow);
            IWebElement option = elementToShow.FindElement(By.XPath("//li/span[contains(text(),'" + filterOption + "')]"));
            Actions action = new Actions(driver);
            action.ClickAndHold(parentFilter).MoveToElement(option).Click().Build().Perform();
    }
```

Comment: Please share your selenium code that is interacting with this list.

Comment: `public void SelectFilter(string filterOption)
        {
            IWebElement elementToShow = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//ul[@class='dropSelect']"));
            ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].style='display: block;'", elementToShow);
            IWebElement option = elementToShow.FindElement(By.XPath("//li/span[contains(text(),'" + filterOption + "')]"));
            Actions action = new Actions(driver);
            action.ClickAndHold(parentFilter).MoveToElement(option).Click().Build().Perform();
}`

Comment: code is difficult to read in a comment.  please edit your question to include the code snippet.

Comment: @BreaksSoftware please check added code snippet

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your code is attempting to directly modify the style using ExecuteScript.  Instead, the code should emulate what a user does by executing a Click() method on elementToShow.  This should open the list, allowing you to find your target option.

Comment: @KalyaniThosar, did this answer help you?